# Looking for a software is able to simulate each situation and verify the results of Texas Hold'em

Tags: texas-hold-em, software

A software is able to verify increase/decrease of stacks. For example, what if I do repeatedly, 10000 times the same actions set up below.

In the case of I have AK off, an opponent did 3bet of 9BB and I called. The opponent will do CB when AK aren't on the flop.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you looking for a tool to simulate hand scenarios?

Comment: A tool is able to calculate the situation as I mentioned. Do you know anything??

Comment: Perhaps "pokerprotools" or "pokerstove" are what you're looking for. Search those terms on this site and you should find some detailed answers about their uses.

Comment: Thank you! but they are not what I think. If I can add the function of strategy to these and simulate increase/decrease of chips. That would be great!

Comment: Maybe "Flopzilla". Still not sure what you're asking though. Hope you find some answers :)